# Is it possible to predefine widget values for a page template in apostrophe cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to create a page template that will pre-populate fields for the widgets. For example Side Navigation I want it to place a two-column widget and define the parameters for that widget to place a navigation widget in column one.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible. This would be a good feature to implement, certainly.